# Odd error thrown by typescript compiler when looping over union typed array

Tags: typescript

Here's an example (not a good one :p):

```
type RandomType = {x: number, y: number}
type UnifiedTypes =  RandomType | 0

type ArrayOfTypes = Array<(RandomType | UnifiedTypes)[]>

const newIns: ArrayOfTypes = [[0, {x: 10, y: 201}], [0, {x: 10, y: 201}]]

for(let i=0; i < newIns.length; ++i){
    for(let j=0; j < newIns[i].length; ++j){
        if(newIns[i][j] !== 0){
            newIns[i][j].x = 30 // Property 'x' does not exist on type 'UnifiedTypes'. Property 'x' does not exist on type '0'
        }
    }
}

// Hoewever, when outside of loop compiler runs fine
if(newIns[0][0] !== 0) {
   newIns[0][0].x = 33; // no error thrown
}
```

Narrowing doesn't seem to work when looping through a union typed array so I'm bit lost. Did I miss smt?

By narrowing down which type the indexed element is going to hold, the typescript compiler should be able to figure out the type of the element array in the specified index and hence assignement occurs safely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion when you type of `newIns[i][j]` is understood as `RandomType | UnifiedTypes` at the point. But when you check `newIns[i][j] !== 0` in the loop, the type of `newIns[i][j]` is narrowed to `UnifiedTypes` which is `RandomType | 0` . But, when you check `newIns[0][0] !== 0`, the type of `newIns[0][0]` is narrowed to `RandomType`, so the compiler knows that `newIns[0][0]` has a property `x`. In other words see below down example.

```
type Shape = 'circle' | 'square'
type Color = 'red' | 'blue'
type Item = Shape | Color

const items: Item[] = ['circle', 'blue', 'red']

for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  if (items[i] !== 'circle') {
    console.log(items[i].length) // Property 'length' does not exist on type 'Item'.
  }
}
```

As you're well aware `items` refers to `Item` type and `items[i]` is inferred as `Item`, which is `Shape | Color`. But, when you check `items[i] !== 'circle'`, you narrow the type of `items[i]` to `Color`, because you are excluding the possibility that it is `'circle'` from the union.

You could fix this like this.

`console.log((items[i] as Color).length)`

Comment: When narrowing, the expected type should normally be RandomType not UnifiedTypes & I did mention this behaviour only happens within a loop. Appreciate the effort & and thanks for the lesson bro I get it.

Comment: The real problem with your question is it is narrowing the type of `newIns[i][j]` to `0`. And it's not understood the `RandomType`. I mean complier. Try this `(newIns[i][j] as RandomType).x = 30` include the `RandomType`

Comment: Worked! Don't know how but still this solved the issue. But I don't get why this only happens inside loops. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

This will work if you create a constant for the `newIns[i][j]` element. For her, TS will be able to correctly process the type.

```js
type RandomType = {x: number, y: number}
type UnifiedTypes =  RandomType | 0

type ArrayOfTypes = Array<(RandomType | UnifiedTypes)[]>

const newIns: ArrayOfTypes = [[0, {x: 10, y: 201}], [0, {x: 10, y: 201}]]

for(let i=0; i < newIns.length; ++i){
    for(let j=0; j < newIns[i].length; ++j){
      const element = newIns[i][j]
        if(element !== 0){
            element.x = 30
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, indeed it works now but it doesn't actually address the core problem. Thanks though.